# How to execute and output from XML via Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

How to implement output the existing value from XML file and changed value?
I'm using this code for changing configuration in xml files:

```
[xml]$config = gc $DirectoryPath\Web.config
$config.configuration.appSettings.Item(0).value = "new-value1"
$config.configuration.appSettings.Item(1).value = "new-value2"     
$config.Save("$DirectoryPath\Web.config")
```

I need to get the output of both values (existing and changed).
If I use brackets:

```
(Write-Host($config.configuration.appSettings.Item(0).value) = "new-value1")
```

I'm geting needed output result:

```
value1 = new-value1
```

but the changes in the XML file are not applied.

And also it will be great if I get the existing line number from XML file in output, something like:

```
value1 = new-value1 at line #10
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot output an XML element and assign a new value to it at the same time. Use two statements:

```
Write-Host $config.configuration.appSettings.Item(0).value
$config.configuration.appSettings.Item(0).value = "new-value1"
```

Add another `Write-Host` statement after assigning the new value if you want to output both values.

You can shorten the statements a little by assigning a parent object to a variable first:

```
$appSettings = $config.configuration.appSettings
Write-Host $appSettings.Item(0).value  # output old value
$appSettings.Item(0).value = "new-value1"
Write-Host $appSettings.Item(0).value  # output new value
```

If you're trying to get old and new value in the same output line you could do something like this:

```
$appSettings = $config.configuration.appSettings
Write-Host -NoNewline $appSettings.Item(0).value  # output old value
$appSettings.Item(0).value = "new-value1"
Write-Host " =" $appSettings.Item(0).value        # output new value
```

Or assign the value to another variable first before changing it, and then output both values afterwards:

```
$appSettings = $config.configuration.appSettings
$oldvalue = $appSettings.Item(0).value
$appSettings.Item(0).value = "new-value1"
Write-Host ('{0} = {1}' -f $oldvalue, $appSettings.Item(0).value)
```

As for getting line numbers, XML is not a line-oriented format, so that won't work.